# Simple nodemon.json config to watch all except for certain files

Tags: node.js, nodemon

`nodemon.json`:

```
{
  "verbose": true,
  "ignore": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules",
    "*.marko.js"
  ],
  "watch": [
    "**/*"
  ]
}
```

I'd like for nodemon to watch every file in every directory except for those which I specifically set to ignore.

The above config isn't doing it:

```
[nodemon] files triggering change check: src/template.marko
[nodemon] matched rule: **/src/**/*
[nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/0
```

It doesn't restart.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue earlier, it seems the `nodemon.json` doesn't do the thing, so try to do it in an inline commnad :

`nodemon --ignore '.git'`

(you can put this as a `npm` script as well)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [browser-refresh](https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/browser-refresh). It's not a drop-in replacement for `nodemon` but it does a lot of the same things. `browser-refresh` watches everything and you can configure what you don't want to watch using a `.browser-refresh-ignore` file that is in the same format as `.gitignore`.

Internally, `browser-refresh` uses [ignoring-watcher](https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/ignoring-watcher)

Comment: I actually use browser-refresh in development (it's great, also can't wait for v4 of marko). I actually got used to how browser-refresh works so I wanted to reflect the behavior in nodemon (as another project relies on it)!

Comment: Also I have a question regarding browser-refresh. Is it possible to reuse the same tab when using `process.send({ event:'online', url:'http://localhost:8080/' });`, server restarts always popup a new window?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"ignoreRoot": [".git", ...],
```